# How to get x11 window id of div element rendered in web browser

Tags: x11

I need a way to find out the x11 window id of a particular div element inside a web browser( example firefox ) so that this id can be used to display some kind of video streams.

Any way to do this in either c++ or java?

On reading some posts and going through internet, there seemed to be one which used xwininfo. 
Using this i could only get the window id of the browser but was not able to get id for internal elements. 
Is it possible? If not.. can anyone suggest me any other idea?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked what you can do with [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) and [xdotool-gui](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xdotool-gui/)?

Comment: This seems to be similar to xwininfo with difference of simulated keyboard or mouse events right? might be useful, but when i tried with xwininfo and clicked on the div i wanted, it gave me the window id of the main browser. Its the same case everywhere i click inside the main browser window. :(

Comment: It's highly doubtful that browser exposes the divs elements id to X11, so I don't see any way to do what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you need to get the window ID, from an external program separate from the browser, or from JavaScript, or what?

The div isn't going to have its own X window; most likely the only X window is for the entire web page, or in some browsers maybe even for the entire browser window including toolbars.

Perhaps you can write a plugin. A plugin (at least for now, future specs are looking likely to change this) can have its own X window. Flash does for example.

Comment: Yes.. after looking around a lot, it is apparant that internal elements are not exposed as x11 windows. However, if it is possible to get the x11 id of the whole broswer, how do i get it?

Comment: from where? from a plugin, from an extension, from some other app?

Comment: From either Javascript or a seperate app ( preferable c++ ) running on the same system. As of now, i have used a shell script that parses xwininfo returned value and converts the string to hex value. Was looking for a way to find this in javascript directly.

Comment: yeah, xwininfo or the equivalent written in C/C++ (see XQueryTree function, or xwininfo source code) is probably the best way. I can't think of how to do it from JS because you can't spawn processes or use Xlib from JS.